VScode Virtual environment downloads are going to different paths
I am on windows machine and sometimes my vscode acts strange. I can see in my vscode terminal the path as below which is exactly where my venv is located:

(first_venv) C:\Users\noman\OneDrive - systems_limited\Documents\My_Scripts\discover_work>


My virtual environment is active and I have also successfully downloaded some libraries last week. However, today, when i logged back in and tried to download more libraries in the same venv, they are downloaded to a different path.
I tried restarting my vscode several times, also deactivating venv and reactivating it but still i am not able to download the libraries.
I ran pip show openpyxl to find the library but it's in a different path. The message i see is below (which is a different path than my venv):

Requirement already satisfied: C:\different-path

It happens quite often with my vscode which brings a lot of frustration. I am thinking if i am missing out on some settings or change my preferences.
